# Dropdown menu not staying when I take the mouse over it

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests, I've made this dropdown menu and i don't know for what reason when i take my mouse over it or i remove the mouse from the parents element which has the hover effect the dropdown dissapears, i want it to stay so that the user can select.

```css
.sub-menu{
    display: none;

  }

  .sub-menu ul li{
    margin: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu{
    display: block !important;
    position:absolute;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }

  .sub-menu ul:hover {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px; 
    -o-transition:.3s ease;
    -ms-transition:.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition:.3s ease;
    transition:.3s ease;
    outline: none;
  }

  .sub-menu ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #f69220;
  }

  .sub-menu ul li a{
    color: black;
  }
  .navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu ul li{
    display: block !important;
    color: black ;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; ">
    <ul class="navbar-ul">
    <li> <a routerLink="/home"><img src="" class="navbar-logo" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <!-- logo -->
    <!-- <li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li> -->
    <!-- <li><a routerLink="/aboutus">About Us</a></li> -->
    <li>
        <a routerLink="#">About Us</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Testimonials</a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blogs</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to `margin-top: 15px` for submenu. In these 15px you go away from parent `LI` -> `li:hover` isn't applied -> submenu is hidden.

Change it for `padding`, or set margin to first submenu `li`. Below is a solution with `padding-top: 15px`.

```css
.navbar-ul > li {background: red; position: relative;}

.sub-menu{
    display: none;

  }

  .sub-menu ul li{
    margin: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu{
    display: block !important;
    position:absolute;
    background: yellow;
    padding-top: 15px; /* padding-top instead of margin-top */
    margin-left: -15px;
  }

  .sub-menu ul:hover {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px; 
    -o-transition:.3s ease;
    -ms-transition:.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition:.3s ease;
    transition:.3s ease;
    outline: none;
  }

  .sub-menu ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #f69220;
  }

  .sub-menu ul li a{
    color: black;
  }
  .navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu ul li{
    display: block !important;
    color: black ;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; ">
    <ul class="navbar-ul">
    <li> <a routerLink="/home"><img src="" class="navbar-logo" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <!-- logo -->
    <!-- <li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li> -->
    <!-- <li><a routerLink="/aboutus">About Us</a></li> -->
    <li>
        <a routerLink="#">About Us</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Testimonials</a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blogs</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```